# Dropping accuracy rate by adding more predictors

Tags: machine-learning

I have run some prediction models e.g. Logistic Regression, SVM, decision tree, ... on a dataset. When I add more dimensions (predictors) then my accuracy rates in all models drops . How can I interpret this?

Comment: Are you talking about the accuracy on the test-set or on the training-set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it means that the features that you are adding are either unimportant or even strongly correlated with other features you already have. Your model might therefore pick up a "random" signal in the training set from these features, and then fail to apply it to test data, as it is not a real pattern.

However, interpretation of this kind of problem is very model dependent. Linear Models do not behave the same as decision trees (for example, they are more sensitive to correlated features), so it is weird that they would react the same way. Please detail more if you can.

Comment: You're right and logistic regression does not drop as much as SVM and Decision Tree - actually 3% vs. 13%. How can I find the correlation among the predictors e.g. in scikit-learn, and how can I add less correlated predictors (or drop more correlated ones)?

Comment: For pandas dataframes you can use `df.corr()` and it will give you a correlation matrix. From there you can see which features are correlated. Creating new features is up to you based on domain knowledge. Finally, you can also remove features that are underperforming in the models (based on p-values for logistic or variable importance).